# Unable to locate package virtualenv in ubuntu-13 on a virtual-machine

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-13.10

When i try to run the command:

`sudo apt-get install virtualenv`

The error I get in response is:

`E: Unable to locate package virtualenv`

Comment: You need to install it with `pip` , if you haven't `pip` install with `sudo apt-get install python-pip` then do `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Comment: have a look to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt

Comment: Now it is giving the same error for the first command you told. @KasraAD

Comment: if you are sure that you have execute the command correctly the problem is for your package manager ! so go to current link to correct it !

Comment: thanx very much. I will try and then come here

Comment: I am confused. One after every dependant gives an error of unable to locate for each proceeding file to be installed. What to do now, please. Thanx in advance. @KasraAD

Comment: Yess, if any one wants to have a look at (  installing virtualenv: a basis for the installation of ) django installation, please run this command when the shell opens up in Ubuntu:
    sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
and then:
    sudo apt-get install python-easy_install virtualenv
and then run the commands to simply start the instructions followed on the following link(starting from the section "Setting up a new environment"):
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try This :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 18):

The Ubuntu package is called [`python-virtualenv`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-virtualenv), not "virtualenv".

Comment: if calling `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` you see an error `Package python-virtualenv is not available` than call `sudo apt-get update` firstly

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible that you may not have run `sudo apt-get update`. It worked for me.

Comment: That turned out to be the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add python before virtualenv because ubuntu package is 
python-virtualenv not virtualenv.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Comment: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

you can install it with this instruction :

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.10.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

Answer (score -1):

Yess, if any one wants to have a look at (  installing virtualenv: a basis for the installation of ) django installation, please run this command when the shell opens up in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-easy_install virtualenv
```

and then run the commands to simply start the instructions followed on the following link(starting from the section "Setting up a new environment"):
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: Unable to locate package python-easy_install