# how to install virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04 GCP instance?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install python3 virtualenv. I get the following message when I try to run virtualenv.

```
virtualenv
Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install python3-virtualenv
```

but if I run install command, I get the following error.

```
apt install python3-virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-virtualenv
```

For `python3 -m venv`, I get message to install using `apt-get install python3-venv`
but when I try it, I get the same message.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate
```

I am running this as root.
wget also works.

Comment: Does `python3 -m venv` work?

Comment: What version of python you are using?

Comment: OS came with Python 3.8.2

Comment: Updated main thread with error message I get with  python3 -m venv

Answer (score 73, accepted):

AFAIU the latest versions of Ubuntu removed Python2 altogether so Python3 is now just the Python. Try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Comment: On GCP shell, I get the following error
```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-virtualenv ```

Comment: what if we get `Package python-virtualenv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: @T.Todua I'm too getting your error on Digitalocean

Comment: This outputs Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate

Comment: @MichaelRogers Try `apt-get update && apt-get install python3-virtualenv`

Comment: the only step missing for me was apt-get update

Comment: It also worked for me with `apt-get update`. But how is this related to Python 2 being removed from the latest versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 13):

try type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv
```

and then try again install virtualenv

Comment: This didnt help

Comment: I tried but got this error:

sudo apt install python3.8-venv 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.8-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.8-venv' has no installation candidate

Comment: Trying similar for Python 3.10 and I get `Package 'python3.10-venv' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 11):

This will definitely work:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 6):

The below is very similar to the answer by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd), but my freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 still requires the python version number:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 4):

I also got that problem and was able to solve it by follow means:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

After clicking enter a window pops up. Then you have to check the first 4 boxes, close it and refresh it.
After that the problem should be solved and you're ready to go

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the error `E: Unable to locate package python3-virtualenv`
 because I had to run `apt-get update` first. This was my brand new GCP instance.

Reference: first comment of the first answer in this thread.
[Unable to locate package virtualenv in ubuntu-13 on a virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256891/unable-to-locate-package-virtualenv-in-ubuntu-13-on-a-virtual-machine)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 3):

try the following

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv xyz-venv
```

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha with the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

But `python3 -m venv` no longer works. Use `virtualenv venv` instead. Activate using `. venv/bin/activate` per usual.

Answer (score 1):

First get the updated information and then install the virtual environment with below two command simultaneously.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

For this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate
```

I discovered that I had to first use `sudo -s` to use root privileges. And then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-venv
```

And it worked. I was working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS